# Sufiism - is it a different religion or it is Islam?

Tags: sufism

Adaab.

I don't know much about different sub sects and diversities of Islamic culture but it looks like the Sufi tradition is quite different. They worship on shrine, practices meditation, uses musical instrument and have monk-like Darvishes who participate in religious dance. This differs from many other sects of Islam.

Now, how does Islam (The Quran and Hadiths?) sees them? Is sufiism considered to be Islam ? ([As I have read that Islam is very strict about whether every commandment is obeyed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/65616/can-one-still-be-a-muslim-if-he-she-denies-some-verses-that-he-she-found-outdate/65622#65622))  Is sufiism totally goes with Islamic religion? or it is seen as a different religion?

Update on comment: I am looking for **all**  major perspectives. This includes perspectives from Sufis themselves, Sociologists and other.

Comment: For the purposes of this site, "Islam" covers all groups that identify as Muslim. You might get a better answer if you focus your question on what one particular denomination believes, or make it clear that you're looking for an overview of all major Islamic perspectives.

Comment: Regardless of sects, If a teaching/practice/method/ belief goes *against/isn't_found_in* the Quran/Sunnah/Hadith, then is it really quote "Islam/Islamic".

Comment: @AbduRahman so it is a different religion?

Comment: @GoldPseudo I don't understand your point. yes I am looking for all perspectives.

Comment: @AbduRahman I think not having a mention in religious scripture doesnot necessarily indicate it to be forbidden.  many things aren't mentioned in religious scripture because they were invented later. such as computer programming, electronics, satellites, radio transmission, etc. so we shouldn't assume they were 'banned' according to a religion until and unless its nature of use is going against an existing teaching of religious scripture.

Comment: @Oud I am talking about religious practices, programming/electronics aren't a religious activity or have a sole religious motive while things such as abandoning society is done for religious/spiritual means although it wasn't done by the Prophet hence not part of Islam.

Comment: So may I assume that Sufiism is a different religion? Maybe it has been derived from Muslim population but it is a completely separate religion?

Answer (score 0):

There are different concepts of Sufism among people. However, Sufism is translated as `tasawwuf` which means a mystical practice. In Sufism people follow a `Tariqa` which comes from the order of their Sufis. So they put some other things in Islamic practice which can't be found in Quran and Hadith and Sufi called them `Tariqa`. Don't divide into any sect follow only Quran and Hadith. If you found anything which is different, then authenticate those things with Quran and Hadith if anything contradicts them then only follow Quran and Hadith.

Comment: Thank you for putting valuable information but This does not fully answer my question. I am not looking for an advise I am looking for factual information about whether Sufiism is considered as Islam religion or a different religion.

Comment: Sufis are considered Muslims but they do other odd things which are not in Islam and can't be found in Islamic practices. Sufism is a sect that is derived from Islam with new innovations.

Answer (score 0):

Sufism is an movement that has developed inside Islam. It is a collective name for groups who - besides common Islamic practice - have developed exercises an rules (Tariq) that mostly aim to feel/experience a tight mental contact with God.

Those exercises do not contradict the Quran or the teachings of Muhammad (p.b.u.h) but they don't originate there.

The Sufi tradition arose from early Islamic ascetic communities, which often attracted Christian ascetic schools, the members of which converted to Islam, either collectively or individually. Teachings and traditions in Sufism has parallels with the (relatively scarce) writings of those groups, and most of the Islamic traditions on Jesus (p.b.u.h) have been related by Sufi. Parallels to practices found in Asian religions may come from an indirect cultural exchange or be parallel findings based on the common properties of the human minds and souls.

Sufism has developed in Sunni Islam and most schools are Sunni. Nevertheless, there is also a Shia Sufi congregation, and a Alevite congregation.

The attitude towards Sufism among other scolars differs. For the Alevites, it's an important part of their religion.

Shia Imams have often been and still are often sceptical or hostile towards Sufism in Shia not so much because of the practice but because the Sufi schools have their own Imams in parallel to their own hierarchy.

Among Sunni scolars we find positive as well as sceptical attitudes toward Sufism, Salafi reject Sufism as they teach that nothing should be added to Islam that hasn't been founded by Muhammad (p.b.u.h) and his companions. Radical Salafists denounce Sufi as kafirun but main stream Islam as well as the Sufis themselves see in it a particular practice and tradition inside Islam.

There are also some modern groups in the U.S. who call themselves Sufi but only copy some practice without the religious background and faith. They are not Muslim, and Muslim congregations do not see them as real Sufi.