# Can a Muslim person have a favourite quote from Quran?

Tags: quran, verses

Adaab.

[Islam requires a devotee to follow every lines and words of Quran unaltered](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/65622/51761), and cannot eliminate any single letter or word.

Now, if one claims a **favourite quote** from quran (I am not talking about a relevant quote to a real life context), it automaticallly assumes the other quotes are somewhat less favourite or less acceptable to that person.

Does Islam allowes a devotee/ practicing Muslim to have a more favourite or less favourite quote from Quran Shareef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people have favorite quotes from Quran. It is part of human nature and there is nothing wrong with it.

I have many favorite quotes. One of them is

> **Quran 94:5-6**
> So indeed with hardship is ease. Indeed with hardship is ease.